# How to toggle spell check with a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently I run with spell check disabled globally in IntelliJ as it ends up being more annoying than helpful most of the time. But there are many times where I'd like to quickly toggle it on and off to check the spelling of things I'm unsure of.

My current workflow in this case is to switch over to sublime then hit my toggle spell check key binding there and then jump back to IntelliJ, which isn't really ideal.

After Google searching around for it all I found was "how to disable spellcheck in IntelliJ" which I already know how to do and searching for "toggle inspection shortcut" was also unfruitful. So does anyone here happen to know if there's a way to bind toggle spell check(or toggle an individual inspection) to a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ?

If not I might end up writing my own IntelliJ plugin today as I really really want this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up making the plugin this late-ish afternoon in a couple hours (thank you yole for telling me it couldn't be done without a plugin before I started work on the plugin). I added the spell check toggle I wanted plus 3 custom toggle bindings that can be bound to any inspection you want.

It's currently awaiting moderation to get in the JetBrains plugin repository but you can download the plugin jar [from my website here.](http://mabboud.net/intellij-inspection-keyboard-binder/)

And I put the source code up on GitHub [here](https://github.com/m-abboud/InspectionKeyBinder-IntelliJPlugin)

Comment: Installed your plugin, but it doesn't seem to work. Pressing Cmd + K + S does nothing

Comment: Oh it's out of date with latest intellij I need to update it

Comment: Ah please do then, I am very bad at spelling and constantly need to use the spell checker :)

Comment: Its updated it will be on the plugin repository whenever the approve it in a couple days and here's a link to the built jar if you want it now: https://mabboud.net/file-uploads/InspectionKeyBinder.1.2.2.jar

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do with out-of-the-box functionality is using Analyze | Run Inspection by Name..., selecting "Typo" from the list and then selecting the scope to run it on.

If you want to run it with a single keyboard shortcut, you'd indeed need to write a simple plugin.